# Python's easy_install and custom header/library location

Tags: python, linux, shared-libraries, header-files, easy-install

I am trying to install [`adns-python`](http://code.google.com/p/adns-python/) using linux and had to recompile [`adns`](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~ian/adns/) with some special options, so I can't seem to use `easy_install <tarball>` as I normally would

```
(py26_default)[mpenning@localhost src]$ easy_install adns-python-1.2.1.tar.gz
Processing adns-python-1.2.1.tar.gz
Running adns-python-1.2.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-9cVl4i/adns-python-1.2.1/egg-dist-tmp-vvO8Ms
adnsmodule.c:10:18: error: adns.h: No such file or directory
adnsmodule.c:31: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âadns_stateâ
```

`adns.h` is installed under `/opt/adns/include/adns.h`; how can I make easy_install install with a local installation of `adns`?

**EDIT**

After the attempt below, I still find an `ld` error, even though I exported `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`...

```
(py26_default)[mpenning@localhost src]$ ls /opt/adns/lib/
libadns.a  libadns.so  libadns.so.1  libadns.so.1.2
(py26_default)[mpenning@localhost src]$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/adns/lib
(py26_default)[mpenning@localhost src]$ C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/adns/include easy_install ./adns-python-1.2.1.tar.gz
Processing adns-python-1.2.1.tar.gz
Running adns-python-1.2.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-x68T9f/adns-python-1.2.1/egg-dist-tmp-MpCzMP
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ladns
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
(py26_default)[mpenning@localhost src]$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used to find a shared library at runtime (when an executable is run), not during linking.

To build the extension, unpack the tarball and run:

```bsh
python setup.py build_ext -I/opt/adns/include -L/opt/adns/lib -R/opt/adns/lib
```

To install:

```bsh
python setup.py install
```

You could specify build_ext options in `setup.cfg`:

```bsh
[build_ext]
include_dirs=/opt/adns/include
library_dirs=/opt/adns/lib
rpath=/opt/adns/lib
```

in this case you could run easy_install directly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this

```
INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/adns/include easy_install adns-python-1.2.1.tar.gz
```

if it is not working please try with `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` or `C_INCLUDE_PATH`

Comment: What server is that? Also please try to install complete development stack 'build-essential'(for c) and 'python-all-dev'(for python). then try the same command.

Comment: The install fails because of `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ladns`... at this point, it has nothing to do with python devel libs or c build tools