# Python readline - how to link ncurses built in home directory?

Tags: python, readline, ncurses

I don't have root access to the Linux server I'm working on.

I'm trying to install [`readline`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/readline/) into a Python installation in my home directory, but building it requires the ncurses library.

I've built ncurses with the prefix set to my home directory, but now I'm stuck trying to link it so that `ld -lncurses` finds it.  I've tried exporting my `$HOME/lib` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`; it did not help.

Is there an option for setup.py to specify what paths to search for the appropriate library?

Comment: related: [Python's easy_install and custom header/library location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889800/pythons-easy-install-and-custom-header-library-location)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, figured it out!

As simple as:
`export LDFLAGS=-L/$HOME/lib`

Not sure if necessary:
`export CFLAGS=-I/$HOME/include`
`export CPATH=-I/$HOME/include`